# liberty java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getLargeUpdateCount not implemented

Tags: java, jdbc, websphere-liberty

Migrating from **websphere liberty 16** to **19.0.0.1** I face this exception: 
Closing a connection after running a Stored Procedure, I get following exception:

> EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of
>   method "callStoredProcedure" on bean
>   "BeanId(UPD_TIMBRI_EAR#UPD_TIMBRI_EJB.jar#StampsSaver, null)".
>   Exception data: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   getLargeUpdateCount not implemented   at
>   java.sql.Statement.getLargeUpdateCount(Statement.java:1092)   at
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.v42.WSJdbc42CallableStatement.getCompatibleUpdateCount(WSJdbc42CallableStatement.java:46)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.impl.DatabaseHelper.getUpdateCount(DatabaseHelper.java:336)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.closeWrapper(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:306)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcCallableStatement.closeWrapper(WSJdbcCallableStatement.java:146)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:152)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:110)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.closeChildWrappers(WSJdbcObject.java:193)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:150)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:110)
>     at
>   com.ibm.rtv.timbri.ejb.StampsSaver.callStoredProcedure(StampsSaver.java:163).....

Code:

```
Connection stampConn = stampDS.getConnection();
stampConn.setAutoCommit(false);
try {
    CallableStatement pstmt = stampConn.prepareCall("{call GRANTUSERSTAMPS()}");
    if (pstmt.execute()) {
        logger.logp(Level.FINEST, sourceClass, sourceMethod, "StoredProcedure OK");
    } else {
        logger.logp(Level.FINEST, sourceClass, sourceMethod, "StoredProcedure KO");
    }
    ;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("could not get JDBC connection: " + e);
    } finally {
        stampConn.close();
    }
```

In liberty gitHub seems that issue is fixed from FP 18.0.0.3. 
Maybe I'm somewhere wrong.

Comment: hi, this looks like a bug in Liberty. Can you raise an issue on github please? https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While awaiting a fix, it might be possible, if neither your application nor other features in the server rely on capability that is new in the JDBC 4.2 spec, to work around the bug by temporarily switching to the jdbc-4.1 feature.

To do this, look for jdbc-4.2 in your server configuration (usually server.xml) under the featureManager element and replace it with jdbc-4.1.

```
<featureManager>
  <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
  ... other features
</featureManager>
```

It is possible that the jdbc-4.2 feature might not show up here if it is implied by other features, in which case you can simply try adding jdbc-4.1 as shown in the above example, which will either override the use of jdbc-4.2 or cause a conflict with it, depending on the exact requirements of the other features involved. If there is a collision, then this temporary workaround won't be possible.

Comment: Thanks all. I discover that Oracle DB driver i was using is not compliant to jdbc-4.2 feature (ojdbc6.jar). Using ojcbc8.jar problem is SOLVED.